# Why does solder smell of incense?

Tags: soldering, lead-free

Sorry for the general nature of this question. But I have always asked myself what makes solder fumes smell of incense.

Comment: Burning flux. It's a mild respiratory irritant. https://www.elexp.com/Images/Health_Hazards.PDF

Comment: Mainly to get hippies interested in electronics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Resin core" is incorrect, it is "***Rosin*** core", and rosin is different, albeit from the same source. Pine tree ***resin*** is heated to remove the volatile elements in it such as turpentine, leaving behind a solid brittle substance called ***rosin***. That rosin will melt again when heated but is difficult to burn and it contains a mild acid. When it melts, the acid etches the metal surfaces so that the solder sticks. If solder had *resin* inside, it would result in flames when you used it and leave behind carbon deposits.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I use rosin frequently as a violin player, but I wasn't sure about the different technical terms for it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you use the standard spools of solder, look closely at the label. It will say "resin-core solder", or something like it. The solder actually contains a core of resin which acts as flux to make a good solder joint possible. It is the hot resin which you smell.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, thank you. Incense is just another type of resin.

Comment: @Quasilattice - If you have a good magnifier, take a bit of solder and slice the end off with a razor blade or very sharp knife. You will be able to see the rosin core.

Comment: Why the downvotes?